# Inbox message's activity indicator showing negative number

Tags: bug, user-interface, global-inbox

Due to some reason, the recent inbox messages indicator is showing a negative number.

NB: all of my messages are read.

[image]

Comment: That happens when you travel into the future and read your notifications before they are sent. A known bug with unofficial TARDIS'.

Comment: I searched meta before posting this but didn't see any related questions.

Comment: Do you by any chance happen to know what you did/what happened that might have caused it?

Comment: as far as I remember, I opened this message yesterday but didn't notice whether there was this indicator count showing or not(even if, I'm pretty sure there wasn't any -ve count), but today morning I saw this -ve count over there.

Comment: Possibly a read notification was deleted while you were on the page?

Comment: Limiting it is probably handled correctly, I hope, in the backend, but the frontend could just be getting confused as a result of updates arriving at different relative times and/or updates that particular tab didn't receive. While knowing the actual cause is helpful, the general solution is to have the code not permit it to be displayed as < 0, as any such value is invalid. Ideally, the frontend software upon seeing such an invalid value would trigger an AJAX call to get the correct, current value from the backend.

Comment: Is it showing like that in only one tab, or does it show that way when you open a new page/tab (i.e. is it a single tab/page that's confused or is the number invalid in the database and persistent on multiple pages when you open them)?